# Multiple use of android camera input stream

Tags: android, camera

Is there a way to share the Android camera stream input to 2 different applications or to 2 different classes in the same application simultaneously? What I want to do is some image processing and in the same time share the input to a server.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Except for very special cases, open camera is a device-wide singleton, and only one preview callback may be active at any time.

But you can write your own mechanism to invoke many callbacks, even for other apps.